# Regex to match strings with substring "/status" unless it contains "subscription/status"

Tags: regex

I know how to match strings that end with "/status": `^.*status$`.

However, I don't want this to apply to strings that end in "subscription/status".

Your help is much appreciated!

EDIT: I'm using a Javascript library to execute a mongoDB query. This is what I have so far:

```
const query = {
  "handler_url_str": {
    "$regex": "^.*status$"
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, this matches *all* documents that end in "/status".

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i'm executing a mongodb query via javascript library. will update my post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"$regex": /^(?!.*subscription\/status$).*\/status$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dA6hfQ/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*subscription/status$)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if, after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`), there is `subscription/status` at the end of the string
- `.*` -  any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `/status`  - a literal substring
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: your answer did not work but your demo did. i think you meant to include the escaped forward slashes

Comment: @robinnnnn: Do you mean  you used `"$regex": /^(?!.*subscription\/status$).*\/status$/`?

Comment: yes, the forward slashes must be escaped with a backslash

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```
"$regex": "^.*(?<!subscription)\/status$"
```

## Explanation

- `^.*` - start with zero or more characters
- Followed by

  - `(?<!subscription)\/status` - `/status` not preceded by `subscription`
- `$` - end of pattern

Comment: `(?!subscription)` is redundant in this pattern, it would only work if it were a look*behind*.

Comment: @ShammelLee i tried this but ended up with a "preceding token is not quantifiable" error: https://regex101.com/r/dA6hfQ/2

Comment: @robinnnnn I see. My solution is for PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression) [regex101.com/r/uHXs8K/1](https://regex101.com/r/uHXs8K/1)

Comment: @ShammelLee gotcha. thanks. apologies for not specifying sooner.

Comment: [New PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/uHXs8K/2). Previous link used JavaScript.